# How to get certain strings and it's respective values in a file and copy them to another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have file named input.txt.gz like this,

```
<hello script="2.5">
<welcome>
     <hgsdhjaghjdghjagdjhgjdhgdajhgdajhgdhjjgfkjg
     <number new="0x0000-0x3FF" Id="bhi" Range="4" no_id="CS_hello" />
               
          <----jsdjhsdjndkjjdhjdJHksdkjdnknnddnekfgrejgjorgj jregjgkrjglrjgojggjorjg--->
          <number new="0x02" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000012" no_id="hi_all res" />
          <number new="0x04" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x0000023f" no_id="d. hwd mas" />
          <---- dfiuhdwiudi iwqdidffenfj odwqjdjqwgru jdqkkjwfkjfwn odHHOIJD JSDNKS nsk---->
          <number new="0x06" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000f22" no_id="sjkdnkl jdsnj (Sedk)" />
          <number new="0x08" Id="bhi" Unit="0" Range="4" info="0x00000f1b" no_id="dm o_1_3k_2_0" />
    <---bdheuh jwdhjwdkiwh---->
          <number new="0x32" Id="bhi"  Range="4" info="0x000012f5" no_id="HES kd" />
          <number new="0x336" Id="bhi" Range="4" info="0x00000df2" no_id="dnkwn" />
<--adhhj jdwjdkkj jsSDjkasdj jefnflefk kjsjfoekfle kajfofkp ksaokdfpef---->
<---the end of file---->
```

From this file I need to get `new` and `info` string values and save it to another file named output.txt.

output.txt

```
new="0x02" info="0x00000012" no_id="hi_all res"
new="0x04" info="0x0000023f" no_id="d. hwd mas"
new="0x06" info="0x00000f22" no_id="sjkdnkl jdsnj (Sedk)"
new="0x08" info="0x00000f1b" no_id="dm o_1_3k_2_0"
new="0x32" info="0x000012f5" no_id="HES kd"
new="0x336" info="0x00000df2" no_id="dnkwn"
```

how ever with my current code im not able to do this.

This is my current code

```
import gzip
with gzip.open("input.txt.gz", "rb") as fin:
     with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
           for line in fin:
                if line.decode('utf-8').strip():
                   line = line.decode('utf-8').strip("\n' '")
                   cols = line.split(" ")
                   if len(cols) >= 5:
                      print(cols[1], cols[5])
```

Comment: Try: `cols = line.split()`

Comment: `line.split(" ")` will create empty fields if there are several spaces. Better do `line.split()` or, as much as I hate xml, a xml parser like lxml

Comment: your input xml has strange quoting inside.

Comment: It should parse using XML library insted of string split and join

Comment: Mind the exact characters. You have written `”` which are RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARKS or unicode character U+201D. A xml file should contain `"` which are QUOTATION MARKS or unicode character U+0022. Do you really confirm that?

Comment: sorry i have corrected the typos.

Comment: You have written `< number ... \>` with a space between the `<` and the`n`. This is enough for the text to be invalid xml. Are really those spaces present in your file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `re` to parse each line.  Here's the [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Np2cxF/1) I've used, but you can update as required.

```
import gzip, re
pattern = r'(new=\"\w+\").*(info=\"\w+\")'

with gzip.open("input.txt.gz", "rb") as fin:
    with open("output.txt", "w") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            for match_new, match_info in re.findall(pattern, line.decode('utf-8')):
                fout.write(f'{match_new} {match_info}\n')
```